# What is the current regulatory progress regarding autonomous aircraft carrying passengers?

Tags: faa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, aircraft-certification

Are there any lobbying groups working towards this? Has there been any word whatsoever from the FAA on this topic yet?